# aws program success in console but no data shown in dynamodb in aws console

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Recently I started working on aws `**dynamodb**`. I was using a program taken from aws website to create table and add entries to it.

In console it shows success but in my account it is not showing anything. no table!! no data !!

I am using [this aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaDocumentAPICRUDExample.html)  program.

[image: aws program output]

It gives success message at the end of run. But when I opened dynemodb there is no table or data in aws management console!!

From where it is adding? and how to get it in my console's dynamodb?

Comment: The link you posted says: "This code sample assumes that you have already loaded data into DynamoDB for your account by following the instructions in the Creating Tables and Loading Sample Data section." Have you done that?

Comment: Are you looking in the correct AWS region for the DynamoDB table?

Comment: @jarmod ohh yes you were right , my region was wrong.. I wrote `us-east-2c` instead of `us-east-2`.. now it is appearing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jarmod

ohh yes you were right , my region was wrong.. I wrote `us-east-2c` instead of `us-east-2`.. now it is appearing.